# Best error log to email ? error_log() vs mail()

Tags: php, sendmail, error-logging

I was just wondering what is the best way to log my server errors through email ?

`error_log()` can indeed send log to an email address with limited possibilities, but was designed for error logs, when `mail()` is design for email with more customization possibilities, but wasn't designed for errors in particular.

Can I encounter performances problems with one of them, what would be the best way ?

Comment: Are we talking about pure php errors? custom exceptions? custom errors? plain messages that you consider messages? The reason I ask is because if it's pure php errors, it might be better to simply watch the error-log file and email yourself a summary once an hour or day.

Comment: I have an API which return custom json error code to my app, and I want to track them to know when a user get an error (like "wrong sql request for this request to the API") so I can know why the error produced this way.
So custom errors-mesages (i want to gather error code, copy of sent request and user session id)

Comment: Hmm if it's somethng like that, I would personally save it to database and email a report once an hour or so.